# dirent d_name string showing unexpected values in gdb

Tags: c, recursion, readdir, dirent.h

I am working on a unit test for a program that walks through a file system on a POSIX based OS and I can not figure out a way to use NFTW to walk it without a bunch of global variables so I am using dirent.h readdir() for a solution. To test the logic of the recursion I made this function and it recurses down one directory but ends in a segfault recursing down to a second one.

```
int recurse_dir(DIR *directory)
{
    struct dirent *direntry = readdir(directory);
    while(direntry != NULL)
    {
        struct stat file;
        lstat(direntry->d_name,&file);
        if(S_ISDIR(file.st_mode) && strcmp(direntry->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(direntry->d_name,"..") != 0)
        {
            printf("%s:\n",direntry->d_name);
            DIR *subdirectory;
            subdirectory = opendir(direntry->d_name);
            recurse_dir(subdirectory);
            closedir(subdirectory);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(direntry->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(direntry->d_name,"."))
            {
                printf("%s\n",direntry->d_name);
            }
        }
        direntry = readdir(directory);
    }
}
```

I tested it with gdb and found that the d_name variable which the man page described as a null terminated string of the current file's name was filled with what looked like the entire directory stream of file names intermixed with a bunch of null's and other escapes. I am posting an example below. Have I just misunderstood what the d_name variable meant?

`.gtkrc-2.0\000\000\bL\f@\000\000\000\000\000\303e0x\261\233-\a \000\b.kshrc\000\000\000\000\000\000\b)\000@\000\000\000\000\000Wa\340\315\366\310y\a\030\000\004src\000\004\037\000@\000\000\000\000\000\030\313\060\232\256\024\245\a \000\004Downloads\000\000\000\004\237\n@\000\000\000\000\000>5\321{\266-\004\t \000\004."...}`

Comment: When do you do the error checking?  You should use `while ((direntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)` for the loop control to save writing the call to `readdir()` twice. Don't forget that you need to pass the path to the directory — and create it — which mean you should pass that to this function.  Otherwise, you won't be able to open directories reliably.

Comment: Presumably you're missing a `.` in `if(strcmp(direntry->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(direntry->d_name,"."))`.

Comment: you must check `if (subdirectory = opendir(direntry->d_name))` so it is not NULL.

Comment: GDB prints the whole 255 or 1024 byte buffer, or thereabouts.  The relevant part is `.gtkrc-2.0\000`; the file name in there is currently `.gtkrc-2.0`.  The rest is debris — irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have not misunderstood.  You are simply paying attention to data that isn't really meant for you.  In C/C++, a null-terminated string is just that -- a null-**terminated** string.  Characters in the buffer past the null could be anything, and are not intended to have any meaning for the consumer of the string.

You may see this phenomenon for a couple of common reasons:

1. Collections of string literals are often stored in contiguous memory, separated by single null characters.  If you just look at the memory, you'll see lots of strings.
2. String buffers are typically only written out to the null.  So if a fixed-size buffer contains a string that doesn't fill it completely, the excess bytes will still have whatever was written there before.